# Table sheet like data in symfony2 form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, tabular

I need to have this type of data in my form :

```
value11, value12, value13 ...
value21, value22, value23
value31, value32, value33 
value41, value42, value43
...
```

This is how the form should look like :

[image: form design]

Is there any form type that can do that automatically or the form must be created manually? There is collection type but its seems cant fit in my case. I am planing to serialize data from this table sheet and story it to single db table column (single property of entity class).

Is there any better way to store table sheet data type presented in this example? Preserving all values in their own entity properties is not an option, because there will be plenty of table data in that form.

Comment: I have some idea how you might do this but it would help to know the structure of the data you are planning to serialise. Is it just coming from a 1d array? If so how do you decide when to start a new row?

Comment: Number of columns are fixed for all the tables in that form. Dimensions of tables are : 8x8, 8x7, 3x3, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried couple of solutions and this is best result by my opinion:

**Step 1.**

Creation of macro for generating tableSheet in separate twig file (for later usage in other forms).

```
{# in Default:form.html.twig #}
{% macro tablesheet(name, rows, colums, titles) %}
   ... titles header ...
   {% for i in 1..rows %}
      {% for j in 1..colums %}
   <input name="{{ name }}_{{ i }}{{ j }}" type="text" class="flat-form" />
      {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

**Step 2.**

Import macro and create tables of input fields, in add/edit template :

```
{% import "ProjectSomeBundle:Default:form.html.twig" as forms %}
...
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ forms.tablesheet('table1', 4, 3, {0:'col1', 1:'col2', 2:'col3'}) }}
{{ forms.tablesheet('table2', 7, 3, {0:'col1', 1:'col2', 2:'col3'}) }}
...
</form>
```

**Step 3.**

Create jQuery function to serialize/deserialize form (input elements with flat-form class attr in this case). For serilize I used something like this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/ . Serialized values are stored in single entity filed as string and saved to db like that.

How it's works :

on opening edit form, jQuery deserialized data from that entity field and loaded to tablesheet input fields. Before sending it back (post) to server values are collect and put in that same field via serialized function.

Answer (score 4):

You should create an entity class with x , y and value properties.

x & y being unique combinations, representing the position in your matrix.

This entity does not have to be stored in your database and can only be used to generate the form.

Then create a form-collection which renders your fields in this matrix form.

Finally: use a DataTransformer to transform the collection of entities to an array as desired.

Now save the array in your database.

Comment: Thanks for response, I did try that, but it was too complicated for implementation. I have found a simple solution for problem, after completing the coding I will paste it here and close the case :) Thanks once again nifr